# нужно ли при вызове revert коммита, фиксировать изменения

Tags: git, github, gitlab

хочу проверить вызовет ли Revert коммита конфликт, 
нужно ли при этом фиксировать изменения,  или это не обязательно

Comment: Попробуйте. В чём вопрос то?

Comment: Вопрос удаляются ли данные, которые относятся к коммиту из индексов и рабочего каталога. То есть сделать git revert commit, затем сделать git add file и git commit -m "new", вернет все в первоначально состояние

Comment: revert - это просто: наложить обратный патч (эквивалентно изменению в редакторе ручками) и коммит этих файлов. Обратный патч получается с диффа коммита, который откатывается, просто меняются плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 1):

если в рабочей копии или в индексе есть изменения, которые затрагивают какой-либо из файлов, который изменялся и в ревертируемом коммите, то команда `revert` возвратит ошибку:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    файл1 файл2
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
fatal: revert failed
```

---

поэтому: да, надо предварительно зафиксировать (`commit`) или отложить (`stash`) изменения в тех файлах, которые были изменены в ревертируемом коммите.